# Mock WCF service reference exposed through a third party DLL

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, unit-testing, moq

Our application integrates with a WCF webservice through a dll reference and WCF configuration entries in the client application's web.config. When I try to mock the webservice I receive an "Could not find default endpoint element that references contract in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this co..." error. 
To resolve the issue, I have added the corresponding bindings from the web.config into the test project's app.config file and set it to "copy always" so it is copied to the bin\debug folder but I still get the error.
How should I resolve this issue?

```
using Payments.ServiceReferences.PaymentServiceProxy;
public interface IPaymentsAPIClientGenerator
{
    PaymentServiceClient PaymentServiceClient { get; }
}

using Payments.ServiceReferences.PaymentServiceProxy;
public class PaymentsAPIClientGenerator : IPaymentsAPIClientGenerator
{
    public PaymentsAPIClientGenerator()
    {
    }
    public PaymentServiceClient PaymentServiceClient
    {
        get
        {
            var paymentServiceClient = PaymentVaultProxyFactory.GeneratePaymentServiceClient();
            return paymentServiceClient;
        }
    }
}

[TestMethod]
public void IfTheSecondPaymentFailsThenTheFirstPaymentShouldBeVoided()
{
    //Arrange
    var iPaymentsAPIClientGeneratorMock = new Mock<IPaymentsAPIClientGenerator>();
    var paymentServiceClient = new Mock<PaymentServiceClient>();
    iPaymentsAPIClientGeneratorMock.SetupGet(counter => counter.PaymentServiceClient).Returns(paymentServiceClient.Object);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web.config for the project that generated that dll should have the binding configuration. If you reference the dll as a project reference in vs then it should  use whatever setting was built in, otherwise, the most straight forward solution would be to copy the binding to your test application's configuration.

Comment: I tried that but it does not work. I have copied the binding to the app.config file in the test project and set it to Copy always. I also see that the app.config file shows in the bin\debug folder of the test project but I still get the same error.

Comment: Are you sure you are copying all of the configuration  from the dll's app.config to your test application's app.config, most importantly, the system.serviceModel section? The application will load configuration elements from it's scope. You should not have to but you can also override the endpoint configuration through code in your test constructor.

Comment: Yes all of it is there. I am thinking that the created mock (in the unit test) does not match with the bindings present in the app.config.

Comment: Are you using Dependency Injection? if so are setting up your services correctly the test app?

Comment: The client application was missing the  <configuration>\<system.serviceModel>\<client> node. Once I added this node to the app.config the unit test started to work.